# create database and table automatically with docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I am uploading an environment with docker-compose but I want to automatically create a table in docker-compose. However it is not working.

docker-compose

```
mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=one
        networks:
          - network1
        volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

/dump/initdb.sql

```
create database one;
use one;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10001 ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

COPY initdb.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.sql
```

Make sure this is in the *same* directory as the `initdb.sql` script.

Now in your compose:

```
mysql:
    build: ./dump
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=one
    networks:
      - network1
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
```