# Connecting Spring Boot dockerized app to a MySQL dockerized server

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Spring Boot app, in which section of `application.yaml` is like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: ${MYSQL_USER}
    password: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}:${MYSQL_PORT}/calculator?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
    initialization-mode: always
```

I've built the image by using `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I'm trying to pass important env variables from `docker-compose.yaml` to the Spring boot app image. So my `docker-compose.yaml` is like this:

```
version: "3"

services:

  app-calculator:
    container_name: calculator-container
    image: dockerhub-user-id/calculator-image:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: calculator
      MYSQL_HOST: mysqldb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306

  mysqldb:
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\Miljan\Desktop\dbDirectory:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: calculator
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Once I go to Docker Desktop and see the container which have two defined conainers, Spring boot app is telling me:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'calculator'
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Ok, then there is no calculator database to connect to. Can you try typing in mysql cli the following: `CREATE DATABASE calculator;` , it should fix the problem for connecting. But it depends on what are you trying to achieve. Is this sufficient for your use case?

Comment: Tnx for the advice, I already managed to do this manual creation. But I want Docker to do it :) I'm learning and practicing.

Comment: You could create a script or provide a database dump that will invoke when the container starts for the first time.
I found this StackOverflow question that seems similiar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428866/create-database-and-table-automatically-with-docker-compose).

U can also find more information on [docker hub MySQL docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) in the "Initializing a fresh instance" section